# Стиль при :hover применяется на следующий элемент

Tags: html, css

Это как? Почему следующему элементу а не ему самому?????
Как сделать так что-бы стиль работал нормально?)

```css
.action {
  padding: 6px 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-action {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin: 0 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-action:after,
.btn-action:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  transition: .25s;
}

.btn-action:after {
  width: calc(100% + 12px);
  height: 100%;
  left: calc(-12px / 2);
  top: 0;
}

.btn-action:before {
  height: calc(100% + 8px);
  width: 100%;
  top: calc(-8px / 2);
  left: 0;
}

.btn-action:hover+.btn-action:after,
.btn-action:hover+.btn-action:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="action">
  <div class="btn-action atack">Атаковать</div>
  <div class="btn-action change-weapon">Сменить оружие</div>
  <div class="btn-action healing">Лечиться</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.btn-action:hover+.btn-action:after` - так ты сам и указал - выбрать следующий, за элементом с hover

Comment: @Grundy а, ой, затупил, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вспомогательные элементы before и after необходимо писать с `::`, а не `:`
`.btn-action:hover::after` - при наведении на .btn-action применять стили к элементу `::after`

```css
.action {
  padding: 6px 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-action {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin: 0 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-action::after,
.btn-action::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  transition: .25s;
}

.btn-action::after {
  width: calc(100% + 12px);
  height: 100%;
  left: calc(-12px / 2);
  top: 0;
}

.btn-action::before {
  height: calc(100% + 8px);
  width: 100%;
  top: calc(-8px / 2);
  left: 0;
}

.btn-action:hover::after,
.btn-action:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="action">
  <div class="btn-action atack">Атаковать</div>
  <div class="btn-action change-weapon">Сменить оружие</div>
  <div class="btn-action healing">Лечиться</div>
</div>
```

Comment: _Вспомогательные элементы before и after необходимо писать с ::, а не :_ - для обратной совместимости браузеры понимают обе формы.

Comment: @Grundy да, но `:` обычно пишут для состояний элементов в основном

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, и это ни на что не влияет ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: так нет разницы как писать? можно и `:` и `::`?

Comment: @Grundy `:after` - синтаксис CSS2, `::after` - синтаксис CSS3

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, это не мешает работать обоим вариантам

Comment: @ПростаMiha да, нету разницы, но для вспомогательных элементов before и after специально в CSS3 начали писать два двоеточия, чтобы легче их отличать от состояний

Comment: @МихаилКамахин аха, спасибо за инфу